# Writing concise code in C

Tags: c, strcat

```
strcat(msg, ": ");
strcat(msg, buf);
```

Is there a way to do this in one line? I want to make my code cleaner and reduce clutter

Comment: You could just concatenate the two lines, but those are fundamentally two operations.

Comment: You mean other than snprintf?

Comment: `strcat(strcat(msg, ": "), buf);`

Comment: Fewer lines does not mean *cleaner*. Readability and maintainability are more important than brevity.

Comment: It's two operations. Putting them on one line makes the code harder to read, harder to edit, harder to step through on a debugger...

Comment: Use snprintf is the way to go.

Comment: Keep in mind that what some people consider to be "clean and uncluttered" C code, many more people consider to be "opaque and unreadable" C code. Make it readable; the compiler doesn't care either way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing multiple concatenations, try creating a formatted string. Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *before_colon = "Text before colon";
    char *after_colon = "Text after colon";

    // Make a string that is the size of both formatted strings, plus a
    // character for the space, colon, and null character.
    char final_string[strlen(before_colon) + strlen(after_colon) + 3];

    // This works just like any other C formatted function (i.e printf, scanf)
    sprintf(final_string, "%s: %s", before_colon, after_colon);
    printf("%s\n", final_string);
}
```

output:

```
Text before colon: Text after colon
```

Comment: This code requires VLA support, which could be avoided by making use of the `sizeof` operator and initializing arrays instead of using pointers to string literals.

Comment: Alternately, just use `asprintf` and let it handle the memory allocation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified code of Charlie Sale with its own function to count characters in the string. Thus, StrLen is called in array declaration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int StrLen(char* PtrFirstChar)
{
    int n = 0;
    while(*(PtrFirstChar++)) // will evaluate to FALSE when '\0' reached
        n++;
    return n;
}

int main()
{
char *before_colon = "Text before colon";
char *after_colon = "Text after colon";

// Make a string that is the size of both formatted strings, plus a
// character for the space, colon, and null character.
char final_string[StrLen(before_colon) + StrLen(after_colon) + 3];

// This works just like any other C formatted function (i.e printf, scanf)
sprintf(final_string, "%s: %s", before_colon, after_colon);
printf("%s\n", final_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own variant of strcat!

I'm going to use strncat as a basis because strcat is a really bad idea:

```
#include <stddef.h> /* for size_t */
#include <stdarg.h> /* for va_* */

char *
mstrncat(char *d, size_t maxlen, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, maxlen);
    char *ret = d;
    /* Fast-forward */
    for (; *d && maxlen; ++d, --maxlen);
    /* Reserve a space for the terminator */
    if (maxlen)
        --maxlen;
    const char *p;
    /* Concatenate parameters one by one */
    while (maxlen && (p = va_arg(ap, const char *))) {
        while (*p && maxlen--)
            *d++ = *p++;
    }
    /* Terminate the string */
    *d = 0;
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    char test[128]="test";
    mstrncat(test, sizeof(test), "1", "two", "3", NULL);
    puts(test);
    return 0;
}
```